# Is it possible to redefine reverse in a Django project?

Tags: python, django, decorator, reverse, monkeypatching

I have some custom logic that needs to be executed every single time a URL is reversed, even for third-party apps. My project is a multitenant web app, and the tenant is identified based on the URL. There isn't a single valid URL that doesn't include a tenant identifier.

I already have a wrapper function around `reverse`, but now I need a way to tell every installed app to use it. The wrapper around `reverse` uses a thread-local to inject the identifier into the resulting URL. I could write this function as a decorator on `reverse`, but I don't know where to do the actual decoration.

Moderately Firm Constraint: I'm already using 3 3rd-party apps, and I'll probably add more.  A solution *should not* require me to modify the source code of all these third-party apps. I don't relish the idea of maintaining patches on top of multiple 3rd-party source trees if there is an easier way. I can make the documentation abundantly clear that `reverse` has been decorated.

The Original Question: Where could I make such a change that guarantees it would apply to every invocation of `reverse`?

Possible Alternate Question: What's a better way of making sure that every URL—including those generated by 3rd-party apps—gets the tenant identifier?
BTW, I'm open to a better way to handle any of this except the embedding of the tenant-id in the URL; that decision is pretty set in stone right now. Thanks.

Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with simply revising every `reverse` to be `your_special_reverse`?  Why not use grep and fix every occurrence rather than confuse future readers of your code?

Comment: I need every third-party app to use `your_special_reverse` as well, and I don't want to fork every third-party app I use. I first ran into this issue with django-notification, but I foresee it being a problem with other apps, as well.

Comment: "every third-party app"?  What volume of 3rd-party apps are you talking about?

Comment: I'm up to 3, and I've seen about 3 more that look like they would be good fits for my project.

Comment: Since no third-party app knows about any other, what possible touch-up of "reverse" are you doing?  Is this something that's better done with a TemplateContext?

Comment: It's a multitenant application, and the tenant is identified based on the URL. There isn't a single valid URL that doesn't include a tenant identifier. The wrapper around `reverse` uses a thread-local to inject the identifier into the resulting URL. BTW, I'm open to a better way to handle any of this except the embedding of the tenant-id in the URL; that decision is pretty set in stone right now. Thanks.

Comment: @Hank Gay: Please update your question with all the additional facts.  Comments aren't the way to present this kind of important valuable information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

only way so that django reverse is replaced by ur_reverse is

```
django.core.urlresolvers.reverse = ur_reverse
```

or if you like decorator syntactic sugar

```
django.core.urlresolvers.reverse = ur_reverse_decorator(django.core.urlresolvers.reverse )
```

which i would not advice(and many will shout), unless you are not willing to change every usage of reverse with ur_reverse

Comment: This works... and is likely to continue working even as you upgrade django :)

Comment: ...even if you are monkeypatching django, it's still the answer to his question

Comment: I'm aware that I want to decorate `reverse`. My question is *where* I should do the decoration?

Comment: my solution you can apply in settings, or anywhere else once

Comment: Thanks. I was worried that doing it in `settings.py` might cause some sort of subtle bug due to incomplete initialization.